# Multiple MS bots calling Same API

Tags: c#, botframework

I have created a MS bot framework API which will be called by more then 1 BOT.

I have created a Class to override the BotAuthentication and add this to the controller.

```
[BotAuthentication(CredentialProviderType = typeof(BotCredential))]
```

Here is BotCredential Class file:

```
public class BotCredential : ICredentialProvider
    {
        public async Task<string> GetAppPasswordAsync(string appId)
        {
            //return the app password
        }

        public async Task<bool> IsAuthenticationDisabledAsync()
        {
            return false;
        }

        public async Task<bool> IsValidAppIdAsync(string appId)
        {
           //return if appid is valid
        }
     }
```

Now in the Controller Post method:

```
MicrosoftAppCredentials credential = new MicrosoftAppCredentials()
{
    MicrosoftAppId ="Appid received from the claim",
    MicrosoftAppPassword = "Appsecret available from the claim"
};
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl), credential);
Activity reply= activity.CreateReply("Some reply");

await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

So now everything working fine for the first time.

For Example I have two Bots Bot1 and Bot2:

First I am sending a message from Bot1 and getting the reply. But after that, if I am sending a message from Bot2, the first message is giving exception with message:

> doesn't match a known conversation

and for the second message from Bot2, it is giving the reply, and again if I am sending a message from Bot1 same thing is happening, and for the first message I am getting the same error and from second message. Onward it is working fine.

Comment: @Katie thanks for the edit and making the question look better :)